# Cannot receive push notification in React Native

Tags: push-notification, react-native

The problem is “cannot receive and take actions on the push notifications in React Native bundle” .

Receiving notifications and opening application by clicking the notifications happens on Native iOS layer, but these notifications cannot be passed to React Native.

For example, FCM provides a subscribe function messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {}) which can inform React Native about the message, then React Native code can perform some actions like fetch data, display content or navigate to specific screens etc.

Currently MCReactModule in react-native-marketingcloudsdk is only able to configure how to receive notification, but cannot handle notifications after receive them.

Comment: We are researching this.

Comment: Hi Bob Lin, any breakthrough? I am trying to receive push notification with `notifee` npm library, it's working fine for iOS, but for Android not able to receive push notification in react native.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you wish as of 20200720.  Please open a voice of customer request through your support representative.

Comment: Bill Mote, I am using `@notifee/react-native` npm library, I am able to get the notification data in React Native (`App.js`) for iOS when I am pressing notification banner in iOS, but for Android, I am not able to get the notification data When I press the notification banner in Android.